# PasswordBox does not apply style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate, passwordbox

I have the following style definitions:

```
<!-- Border -->
<Style x:Key="MyControlBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkKhaki" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
</Style>

<!-- TextBox -->
<Style x:Key="MyTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <Border Name="TextBoxBorder" Style="{StaticResource MyControlBorder}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- PasswordBox -->
<Style x:Key="MyPasswordBox" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Border Name="Border" Style="{StaticResource MyControlBorder}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And the following XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBox}" />
    <PasswordBox Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MyPasswordBox}" />
</Grid>
```

Now I got this result:
[image: A TextBox and a PasswordBox stacked vertically, where the TextBox has a khaki colored, rounded border, but the PasswordBox has no border at all.]

The `TextBox` applies the style correctly, but why does the `PasswordBox` not apply the style?

Comment: Have you tried using something like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for finding out where the border is getting it's values from at runtime? It's possible something is setting the border styles at a higher [Dependency Property Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow `Border` within `ControlTemplate` of `PasswordBox` does not take `MyControlBorder` style.

When you modify `MyPasswordBox` style like this... then it will work.

```
<Style x:Key="MyPasswordBox" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
<Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
            <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="DarkKhaki" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I know it's not the best solution... but I can't figure out why `MyControlBorder` is not applied. It doesn't even work when you get rid of `MyTextBox` style. Then you are left only with `MyControlBorder` and `MyPasswordBox` ...it does not work either.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap the `Border` in another `Border` everything just works as expected (I don't know why).

As a bonus, you can now have `PasswordBox`es and `TextBox`es "inherit" from the same `Style`, keeping things nice and DRY.

```
<!-- Border Style Definition -->
<Style x:Key="MyControlBorder" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkKhaki" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
</Style>

<!-- TextBox and PasswordBox Style -->
<Style x:Key="MyControlInputBox" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Border>
                    <Border Name="Border" Style="{StaticResource MyControlBorder}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- TextBox -->
<Style x:Key="MyTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyControlInputBox}" />

<!-- PasswordBox -->
<Style x:Key="MyPasswordBox" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyControlInputBox}" />
```

Comment: css is awesome, xaml not so awesome :P

Comment: I also added '<Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"></Setter>' to MyControlInputBox, otherwise the cursor was too high.

Answer (score 0):

The `PasswordBox` is strange in this regard, as it is explicitly implemented to show this behavior.

The default control template contains a `Border`, as you can see here:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
   <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
   </Border>
   <!-- ...other markup, triggers. -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

The code for `PasswordBox` (taken from reference source) does the following:

- [`OnApplyTemplate` on line 473](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,473) is called when the control template is applied.

  - [`AttachToVisualTree` on line 476](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,476) is called which is [defined on line 1176](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,1176).
  - [`SetRenderScopeToContentHost` on line 1181](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,1181) is called which is [defined on line 956](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,956).

    - [From line 1014 on](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,1014) it searches a `Border` up the visual tree beginning from the password content host. Note that it searches until it does not find a `Border` anymore, which means it stores the **last** found `Border` within its `_border` field.
  - [In line 1200](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs,1200), if a `Border` was found, its `Style` property is set to `null`.

Consequently, whenever a control template is applied, the `Style` of the **outermost** `Border` is reset. This is still the same in .NET Core and >.NET , as you can see from the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/89d172db0b7a192de720c6cfba5e28a1e7d46123/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/PasswordBox.cs#L1160). This is the reason why [@David Murdoch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765311/6181599) with a redundant nested `Border` works, when the style is applied to the inner `Border`.

Now, what can do? You can either insert a dummy `Border` as a workaround or you have to set the `CornerRadius` directly to the `Border` inside your custom control template.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
   <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="10" Style="{StaticResource MyControlBorder}">
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```